# Xcode Server "Bot Web View" and "Big Screen" not refreshing

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-mavericks, osx-server, xcode-bots

I recently set up a Mavericks Server with Xcode Continuous Integration. I created a bot and the bot itself works well running tests and archiving from a remote git server by polling.

My problem is that when I use the web view to view logs the page does not refresh automatically. As an example if I open the server while a integration test is running or if I start integration tests manually from the web view the information just show the "spinning wheel" like it keeps running, and I have to refresh the page manually to get updated information.

The same happens when I use the "Big Screen" mode that cycles through the bots showing various information. The views never refresh. I thought that was the whole point with Big Screen to have a screen that always show updated information.

I have tried with several different browsers on different machines, and restarted the Xcode service on the server and restarted the server itself with no change. I also tried creating a test project that uses a git repository stored locally on the OS X Server.

Has anyone had similar issues? Does this work at all? I've tried googling but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by using [Auto Refresh Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus/oilipfekkmncanaajkapbpancpelijih?hl=en) for Chrome.  Not the most elegant, but Xcode Server doesn't provide a whole lot in the settings department it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that the bot names didn't refresh. To fix just run an integration on that bot and the names will be updated.

But the webview itself is always refreshing. Did you check your javascipt options?